# installer for distribution visual studio 2008 express

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, installation, windows-installer

I've been doing some research in to installers for visual studio express 2008. I don't much like the standard publish option. I'd rather have a proper windows installer. Am I right in thinking that the only way to do this is to upgrade to the standard edition?

Are there any third party tools which can be used? I've tried googling a lot, but don't seem to be getting anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

There is a free open-source utility called WiX which creates Windows Installer (MSI) packages.  WiX was the first Microsoft app to be released with an open-source license.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX
http://wix.sourceforge.net/

Together with the [Votive](http://wix.sourceforge.net/votive.html) IDE you can create professional-calibre MSI packages.

Comment: thanks for the reply... but on the votive website it does say that "Votive will not work on the Express SKUs of Visual Studio". So it looks like that's not an option. I have tried cyberinstaller but again, need to register that for around 50euros. I am trying to distribute some freeware and it's proving to be difficult! (I don't want to plough lots of money for distributing as I won't make anything from it!)